# Setting Content Disposition with CloudFront/S3 without Signed URLs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have objects with public read access that are restricted to only being served through CloudFront. When I try to pass in a `response-content-disposition` parameter to my CloudFront URL, I get the S3 error:

`Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests.`

I've read that S3 does not allow you to set the content-disposition unless you are using a signed URL, but this isn't an option. The CloudFront requests shouldn't be considered anonymous since they are using the bucket policy for authentication. Is there a way I can configure that to work?

**How can I set the content-disposition without using a signed URL?**

Comment: *"The CloudFront requests shouldn't be considered anonymous since they are using the bucket policy for authentication."* Right, which sounds like you are not actually doing that, and the object is publicly-accessible and being accessed anonymously instead of using an origin access identity (OAI).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you called it! The answer is that you can do it, but the CF distribution must have the option selected to restrict access. Post and I will accept the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Request options like `response-content-disposition` are not supported with anonymous requests, so the error suggests that S3 is not seeing any authentication information present.

In order for CloudFront to authenticate itself to an S3 origin, the `Restrict Bucket Access` origin setting must be set to `Yes`.

The option is very poorly named, because the option does  not actually do anything to restrict access to the bucket.  It should be called something like "Authenticate Requests When Sending to Bucket" because that's what the option actually enables -- use of an Origin Access Identity (OAI) to authenticate the requests being sent to the bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-creating-oai-console

Note that the fact that your setup was allowing requests to pass through anonymously may mean your bucket policy or object ACLs are not sufficiently restrictive.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Adding the "Content-Disposition" header under "Set Metadata" when uploading or editing an object in S3 will work and it will persist even when served through Cloudfront.

Comment: @Jake Good point, though someone might not want to set the metadata when uploading the object, and want to set this header on the fly.

Comment: @Jake I'm not sure I agree that the answer is out of date.  The capability to set `Content-Disposition` in object metadata has been supported in object metadata since I started working with S3, back in 2012.  The fact that OP was using `response-content-disposition` suggested to me that they specifically didn't want to go that route.  Reading the question, now, it might be that I was mistaken in the assumption, but this is the solution to the question being asked -- how to resolve the error from S3 that `Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests.`