# How to force download on amzon s3 only sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a scenario where i have a public s3 bucket with images that are used on a website.

Now, i have read that you may use additional get parameters `?response-content-disposition=attachment;filename=somefile.jpg`, but when i use it i get an error saying that this is not possible for public files and "anonymous" get requests.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests.</Message>
<RequestId>...</RequestId>
<HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

Then, i've read that you may specify that file should be always downloaded by setting file's additional metadata to `Key: Content-Disposition Value: Attachment` in `Properties > Metadata > Add more metadata` (or set these metadata when uploading files via api). But that solution is no good, since i sometimes need to display the file and sometimes offer it for download as an attachment.

Is there a way to make a public file downloadable only sometimes in Amazon S3 buckets?

Comment: I think your two options are to either use pre-signed URLs or to use CloudFront in front of the S3 content and set an S3 bucket policy that restricts access to the CloudFront OAI. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749472/setting-content-disposition-with-cloudfront-s3-without-signed-urls).

Comment: using cloudfront/my own server results in the traffic going through next server, costing bandwidth. what do you mean by the pre-signed url though?

Comment: The issue you have is that anonymous GET requests direct to S3 don't support the content-disposition options. But apparently this does work with signed requests (allegedly, I have no direct evidence), hence offering the client a pre-signed GET URL might work. On the bandwidth concern, if this content is being served to internet clients out of S3 then you're paying for data transfer out whether you serve from S3 or CloudFront or your own origin server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an extra request, creating a temporary signed request like this:

using native AWS php client:

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $pathToFileOnAWS,
    'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment'
));

return (string) $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes')->getUri();
```

when using Laravel simply:

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl( $pathToFileOnAWS, now()->addMinutes(20), ['ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment']);
```

you may also use `'attachment, filename=somename.ext'`